# Xerox WorkCentre 6015NI - Stuck on 092-651 Code: 2880000

Tags: printer, laser-printer

Although not completely honestly advertised as a Linux compatible printer my nice Xerox WorkCentre 6015NI printer stopped working.

The misery started when the printer's black toner needed replacement, a bit earlier than expected, but the black parts of the prints were fading away and the printer was displaying the error message: "093-933 Replace Black Cartridge". I replaced it with an original new one.

The printer still printed in vaguely black and the error didn't disappear. Because it could have been a DOA, the kind internetshop replaced it with another new original one. After replacing, the printer stopped working with another error message: "092-651 Code 2880000"

As suggested on the Internet and Xerox manuals, I have executed the procedures to clear the CTD sensors. I also vacuum cleaned the pathways that transport old toner powder towards the black cartridge.

However, when I turn on the printer, this error code appears. The display mentions to "Contact Support" if the message doesn't disappear.

It's an old printer and I have tried to contact Xerox at first. It happens that the original shop didn't register the printer to my address and warranty is well over. Before attempting another go a Xerox:

Does anyone know a procedure to reset the printer from this situation? I have cleaned some parts and would like to have another go to see if printing works. I have tried diagnostics / CE mode to diagnose some of the sensors and motors. Except for the password protected MFG menu I have tried most options to reset the thing. Is there a 'secret' reset button combination of some kind? Or perhaps a not too invasive operation?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the ADC sensor correctly. *A note, be sure to use a correct vacuum  inside a printer. I would use simple wipeall sheet to catch the toner. A vacuum could create static that can cause damage to the electronic.*

Per the service manual:

[image]

If that don't help, it can be the MCU, but it would cost more, at that point I would value the price cost versus the printer cost.

[image]

Comment: I did clean these ADC sensors. Unfortunately, the 092-651 code doesn't disappear. Thanks!

Comment: @mv_ Then you must continue the step, the cleaning was step 1, after it's the 2, which are the connectors, after if you fall into step 3 it's a board to change. It's why I pasted the complete guide page, you have all steps inside it.