# Xerox WorkCentre/Phaser, Dell, Fuji printer stuck on 092-651 Code: 2010000

Tags: printer, laser-printer, dell, xerox

Related but not exactly the same error: [Xerox WorkCentre 6015NI - Stuck on 092-651 Code: 2880000](https://superuser.com/questions/1471366/xerox-workcentre-6015ni-stuck-on-092-651-code-2880000)

Many people ask the same question regarding this error and no actionable answer beyond vacuuming the printer and cleaning a pair of sensors seems to be available.

Usually the problem goes:

1.Printer says

```
Error 092-651
2010000
Restart printer or contact service if problem persists.
```

2.I [clean the TDS* as per Xerox/Dell/Fuji instructions](https://www.support.xerox.com/en-us/article/en/x_6130_en-O10540)

3.I vacuum the toner receptacles as per [youtube video by Lavigne Claude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlSRrtpFXJg)

4.Error still persists.

What do I do next to recover my printer/copier from this seemingly bricked state?

---

* Toner density sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Today I half incidentally discovered a possible solution - worked for me the first time I tried!

1. Procure a full set of high quality toner cartridges, preferably genuine Xerox ones (I have a pair of the Xerox 6000 line and had some rebranded Dells in the past and this problem seems to be caused by old or low quality toner).
2. Go through all the steps listed in the question.
3. Turn the printer off, remove the old cartridges, do the vacuuming again, clean the TDS's again, and insert the new cartridges. Don't turn the machine on yet.
4. **The new step: press the settings button* and keep it pressed. While still pressing the button, turn the printer on with the mains switch.**
5. (optional) Do all the refreshing and cleansing the service menu gives you two to three times, if you see smudges of unwanted toner on your prints (in my case the yellow one seems to have been the culprit this time).

The machine should start into self-diagnosis and calibration mode. As soon as it starts doing typical printer noises, you can let go of the button. The process takes considerable time (minutes in my case).

Et voila, at least in my case, the printer prints again. I guess it purged itself of all the old toner already dosed into the printing unit and loaded the new toner.

* This button:

[image: Settings button on Xerox WorkCentre 6015]